# How to import an X509 certificate into a smartcard csp in C++ using MS CAPI?

Tags: windows, import, cryptography, certificate, cryptoapi

I've generated a signature key pair on a smart card using windows Smartcard CSP & Crypto API with C++.

Now I need to import a X509 certificate which is related to the same public key into the smart card, but I don't know which function should I use (maybe `CryptImportKey` or `CryptSetKeyParam` ?).

Comment: Have you found a solution? I'm interested in it :)

Comment: No, unfortunately I could not find the solution, so I Just used minidrivers `CardWriteFile` method to create certificate in desired container